# using rake to dump and load database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

How can I specify a directory for dumping/loading my db to yaml?

```
rake db:data:dump_dir
```

created

```
db/2011-08-31_14:10:57_+0100/
```

and

```
rake db:data:load_dir

No such file or directory - <RAILS_ROOT>/db/base
```

My question is whether you can specify a directory name to dump to/load from and how?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the 'dir' parameter, eg:

```
rake db:data:dump_dir dir="my_dir"
```

which will put it in 'db/my_dir' and:

```
rake db:data:load_dir dir='my_dir'
```

which will load it from 'db/my_dir'.

For dumping the directory must NOT exist.
In both cases dirs are relative to db, absolute paths are NOT allowed

Hope this helps.

Comment: Merci Benoit. I edited your answer: added detail about path, changed back quotes which are for code execution in a shell. Ta

Comment: Thanks for the precisions, I approved it.

Comment: Hi, this worked for me, But to get these commands working, you need to install yaml_db gem (https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db), at least for rails 2.3.9. thanks